# Selected template is not respected for home page in Wordpress

Tags: themes, templates, page-template, template-hierarchy, design

I have a theme, and I made two new files for different templates. I can now pick these templates when I post a page:

[image]

This works perfectly when I go to any subpage. I made a page called `Test`, selected one of my templates, and the page shows.

However, my challenge is this doesn't work for the home page.

I have now made my test page the index page:

[image]

However, when I open the page, it does not respect my selection. Instead, it will open the standard theme.

I guess it's caused by some challenge with [the hierachy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), but I don't completely understand why.

Any ideas? :-)

Comment: Do you want to make a subpage the home page ?

Comment: @Beee No, I want my home page to follow a specific template I have made. In practice, my home page will be a fully static HTML page i've made :-) This works fine with subpages, but not the home page

Comment: i'd look into what Jacob suggested. If it's not overriden by a default front-page.php (in the theme).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the hierarchy flowchart on the page that you linked to, Site Front Page will choose `front-page.php` before falling back to behaving like a normal page:

[image]

So if you want to have a specific template for the front page template of your theme you need to make those changes to `front-page.php`, *or* delete `front-page.php` so that it behaves like a normal page.

Comment: Worked! Thanks! I'll make it an answer in 2 min when I am allowed :-)